# What happen if one connects two live phases together?

Tags: wiring, load, stability, phase

If a house is running on 1 phase wire and is flipping instantly or not stable for a short period as it drops from 200v to 170v and return back to 200v in 10 seconds. Would connecting another phase to the first phase balance the electrical loads?

Comment: No, it will not. Problem with the power source or connections. Fix them.

Comment: Regarding the connections, what are the possible reasons behind bad connection or how can I know and identify that bad connection?

Comment: What does "flipping instantly" mean? AC alternates 50 or 60 times a second.

Comment: *What happen if one connects two live phases together?*  Nothing good!

Comment: Just follow all circuit from screw on breaker in panel, clean and tighten all of them. Your voltage drop is abnormal. If it is not help, you power source not good. Do not do it under voltage, breaker should be off.

Comment: @transistor, I was trying to explain sudden drop in voltage. Like when a lamp light is shivering.

Comment: @user263983, yeah it is probably the power source which is causing the lights to shiver every now and then especially during the heavy-load-period. I've filed a complain to the ministry of electricity and I guess I'll wait to see what they will do about it. I hope they would switch to another phase to power my home panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a house is running on 1 phase wire ...

Then all live wires in the house will be at the same voltage.

> ... and is flipping instantly or not stable for a short period as it drops from 200v to 170v and return back to 200v in 10 seconds.

If the supply drops then all the live wires will drop to the same voltage.

> Would connecting another phase to the first phase balance the electrical loads?

If there is only a single-phase supply then you achieve nothing.

If it was a different phase of a three-phase supply you would create a short-circuit, a very high current would flow limited only by the cable resistance and the circuit breakers would trip.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if one connects two live phases together?

When someone (else - phew) did this at work they took out a medium-sized industrial site and the adjacent housing estate. (This was a multi-MVA fault on an 11 kV ring main though.) Don't try this at home, folks.

Well, you won't be able to (unless you have a very special home). Don't try it with regular domestic supplies either. OP should get a qualified electrician to fix their supply problems as we're wandering into 'if you have to ask you shouldn't be doing it' territory.